# Generate the UUID when the input payload is read from external file

Tags: jmeter, http-post, uuid, payload

${__UUID()} is not working when sending the payload content which was read from an external file

1. I'm making a post call with input payload read from an external file.
2. In the HTTPRequest post body data, I'm using this function to read the external file : ${__FileToString(${__eval(./HTTP/payload.txt)},,)}
3. I can verify that data from the external file is read and being used when the post call is being made.

The issue is that, when making the post call, in the payload, against ID element, ${__UUID()} is not replaced/parsed by the UUID value, the static text "${__UUID()}" is being sent in the payload.

How to generate the UUID when the input payload is read from external file ?

Note: i also tried reading the file content line by line in BeanShell PreProcessor, and sending it as body data, same issue, UUID function is not parsed.

```
{
   "id":"${__UUID()}",
    "fname":"Hello",
    "lname":"World"
}
```

Expected result is : ${__UUID()} should be parsed and the actual UUID value should be send as part of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first read (`FileToString`) the file and then evaluate UUID (`eval`)

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(./HTTP/payload.txt,,)})}
```

Answer (score 0):

allowing arbitrary code to come from external files is a risky endeavor. since you're looking for a UUID each time you generate this data, could you just generate a UUID variable and use any random templating language to plug it in?

Comment: thanks Mr. Cat.

agreed, but this is going to be for internal use and not exposed to outside world.

not sure on what it means "use any random templating language to plug it in".

but i tried this approach as well, generated the UUID in BeanShell PreProcessor and put that in vars as well props (key is uuid), the sample payload was changed to the below , but this text "${uuid}" was not parsed with values. tried using eval function as well, was not getting parse, not sure where i am going wrong.

````{
   "id":"${uuid}",
    "fname":"Hello",
    "lname":"World"
}````

Comment: i dug around online and found this as an example:

'Hey {name}, there is a 0x{errno:x} error!'.format(name=name, errno=errno)

which should do what you're expecting, though the syntax is slightly different

Comment: thanks a lot, Mr. Cat for your help !!!!, was able to make it work based on the suggestion provided by user7294900